# Setting a property in model object which will be shared by all controller method of spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model, freemarker

I have few attributes with values I wanted to set in the application scope of Spring MVC. And I should be able to access this in the view layer (I am using freemarker). This value should be loaded only one time during the application startup. What is the best practice to do this in Spring MVC application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `PagePopulationInterceptor` to add values to all the pages:

```
public class PagePopulationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        if (modelAndView != null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("exampleGlobalString", "stringValue");
            modelAndView.addObject("exampleGlobalInt", 2);

            DateTime exampleDate = new DateTime(2005, 3, 26, 12, 0, 0, 0);
            modelAndView.addObject("exampleGlobalDateTime", exampleDate);
            modelAndView.addObject("exampleGlobalDate", exampleDate.toDate());

            modelAndView.addObject("japaneseMonth", exampleDate.monthOfYear().getAsText(Locale.JAPAN));
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/edendramis/freemarker-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/edendramis/PagePopulationInterceptor.java

Answer (score 0):

You can simply annotate a public void method on your controller with **@PostConstruct**. `This method is executed after dependencies have been injected`, and it's invoked exactly ones after the controller instance is created.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wanted to access this attribute (or bean) accessible from the FTL file. How do I do it?